# function composition in natural order in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

We all know and love/hate composition from right to left :

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

What is the "most standard" operator (as in some sort of common library) for natural/left to right composition :

```
(???) :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c
```

which generalizes the common sense operator for values, seen as functions from `()` :

```
(&) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
```

available in a few librairies

PS : if there are none, any side for the name of such operator ? in math, natural composition is very often written ";" but what would be the second best name ? `(&.)` maybe ?

Comment: You may define an `infixr 9` operator as `flip (.)`.

Comment: this is what I usually do, baring some standard operator. it's too bad there are not a blessed prelude, which I imagine would have a syntax for this operator. The many styles of haskell make it unnecessary hard to read. I can imagine newcomers being turned away by simple syntactic things like this

Comment: You can hide Prelude `(.)` then define an overloaded `(.) :: a -> b -> c` that looks at the types of its arguments to decide which way round it works: instance `a -> (a -> b) -> b`; instance `(a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> c)`; instance `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)`. Needs Overlapping instances and Closed Type Families for the result type (or Functional Dependencies). Also needs a strong stomach for perplexing error messages ;-)

Comment: Well, the way the composition operator works is not about Haskell but [Math](http://www.wikizeroo.net/index.php?q=aHR0cHM6Ly9lbi53aWtpcGVkaWEub3JnL3dpa2kvQ29tcG9zaXRpb25fb3BlcmF0b3I) or more preciselly Category Theory. So it is **NOT** a good idea to **NOT** have it. You may always use `f >>= pure . g` for the desired effect (see how we needed `(.)` there). I understand your frustration, as it resembles the property accessor operator in some object oriented languages like JavaScript, which gets operated from left to right. So in Haskell you better use `(.)` with white spaces around.

Comment: Please don't do what @AntC suggests, though. Aside from the fact that no one will expect `f . g` to have two possible interpretations, it won't be able to decide which order is correct for `f, g :: a -> a`, since both `f (g x)` and `g (f x)` would type-check.

Comment: The two notions of composition are equally valid (and need to have 2 distinct syntax of course). In the early days of category, a few authors tried to use the "natural" way, but the mathematic convention won (I'd say say unfortunately). The best is to have both and use the one which suits the best where it is used.

Comment: @Redu [*Seven Sketches in Compositionality*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.05316), a recent category theory book, uses left-to-right composition all along, with `;` as the chosen operator symbol. As nicolas suggests above, it is not such a big deal.

Comment: Note that in Haskell in particular, `f (g x)` actually runs `f` first and only runs `g` if `f` actually looks at its input.  So `f . g` is actually in the correct order.

Comment: @Carl it's the correct order if you "pull the evaluation thread" from the left. if you pull from the right, then `x & (g ; f)` would be the correct order.

Comment: @Carl True but that's just an outcome of Haskell evaluating `(.)` lazily not the reason why it's expression is defined the way it is. You are still expected to reason it's outcome by evaluating first `g` and then `f` in your mind. In such cases where `f` should neglect the result of  `g` then instead of composition you may do like `g >> f`.

Comment: Note that we write types on the right of expressions, so we already use the "natural" convention for types, but, strangely, not for composition. That makes `(f (g (x::TypeX) :: TypeGX ) :: Type FGX)` so applying  `f` on the left ends up with its resulting type on the right. very odd...  If we insist on writing right to left, type should go on the left of expression too. mixing convention makes for needlessly hard to read code, which matters a lot since Type are part of the code in haskell !!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import Control.Arrow
(>>>) :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c
```

Actually, `(>>>)` is more general than that, since it works on any category, not just `(->)` functions. It is frequently used for forward function composition, though.

Answer (score 2):

Function composition is a form of function application. `(.) = (<$>)`, and `(<$>)` is so named because it represents function application (`($)`) through a functor. Similarly, we have reverse function application, `(Data.Function.&)`, and we also have reverse function application through a functor, [`(Data.Functor.<&>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--38--62-). Compared to `(>>>)`, `(<&>)` avoids invoking `Category`, just `Functor`, but, on the other hand, it is a relatively new addition to `base`.

Comment: Thank you. this might be a simpler answer. I actually used it before, and felt like it should have been handy. To clarify, we have `(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` and `x->a` is, for a fixed x, a functor in `a`, giving `(<$>) @ (f = x->_) (a -> b) -> (x-> a) -> (x -> b)`. In Cat-speak the functorial action of *a* representable functor is, up to iso, post-composition (and for *the* representable (x->_) that iso is the identity). likewise for `(<&>) :: Functor f => f a -> (a -> b) -> f b ` which is specialized to likewise for `(<&>) @ (f = x->_) :: (x-> a) -> (a -> b) -> (x->b) `

Comment: On the downside, I think we should use non-polymorphic code when we are "clients". The "implementer" might rely on general polymorphic, categorical structure, but since we as a client dont require it, those implementation detail should not pollute our usage, ideally. Conversely, when we do use it, it should be meaningful, broadcasting that our code is indeed polymorphic over all functor instances.